# Конфликт jquery и vue возможен?

Tags: jquery, vue.js

Имеется подключённый к HTML-документу файл script.js,написанный на jquery. Сам jquery подключён в head через cdn. Что будет,если здесь же через cdn подключить vue и в файле script.js дальше писать уже на vue?Нужно ли также оборачивать код в document.ready?

Comment: Трудно дать ответ, когда не дан код.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Проблем не должно возникнуть, так часто делают, хотя я бы посоветовал писать скрипты которые jquery в одном файле для vue в других. Да и можно, например webpack использовать для сборки.

document.ready для Vue не надо.

Comment: `document.ready`  и для jQuery скриптов не обязателен, если все скрипты находятся перед закрывающим `</body>`, ведь на момент исполнения вся разметка уже есть на странице